# LINQ Join Two DataTables - Define Field Types At Run Time?

Tags: vb.net, linq

Is it possible to create a MergeTables method like the one below where the field types of the fields that are being joined are not known at compile time?

```
Private Function MergeTables(ByVal dtA As DataTable, _ 
                             ByVal dtB As DataTable, _
                             ByVal fieldA As String, _
                             ByVal fieldB As String, _
                             ByVal fieldAType As ???, _
                             ByVal fieldBType As ???)

  Dim test = (From a In dtA.AsEnumerable() _
              Join b In dtB.AsEnumerable() _
               On a.Field(Of ???)(fieldA) _
               Equals b.Field(Of ???)(fieldB) _
            Select New With _
                { _
                    'Specify fields here
                }).ToList()

   Return test
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making your method generic and passing `Func(Of DataRow, T)` instead of strings?

```
Private Function MergeTables(Of T)(ByVal dtA As DataTable, _
                         ByVal dtB As DataTable, _
                         ByVal fieldASelector As Func(Of DataRow, T), _
                         ByVal fieldBSelector As Func(Of DataRow, T))

    Dim test = (From a In dtA.AsEnumerable() _
                Join b In dtB.AsEnumerable() _
                 On fieldASelector(a) _
                 Equals fieldBSelector(b) _
              Select New With _
                  { _
                      .t = 1
                  }).ToList()

    Return test
End Function
```

btw. returning anonymous types from method is not a good practice.

***Calling example***

You can use lambda expression to call that method:

```
MergeTables(first, second, Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("testA"), Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("testB"))
```

Comment: I'm trying to clean up a class which has many LINQ queries that only vary slightly by column names and field types.  Is it better practice to leave them alone rather than consolidating and passing parameters into a method?

Comment: It's always better no to repeat the code, so yes merging similar methods into one is common part of refactoring process.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, I had excluded `(Of T)` in the post. One last question - I'm a little over my head.  How would I initialize the `Func(Of DataRow, T)` variable?  I see that I can create something like `Dim test As Func(Of DataRow, String)`, but I'm unsure how to specify the field.  Any resources I should look into?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The easiest way to go is using lambda expression. I've updated my answer with an example.